# Sql Server Analysis Services Parent Child with non-unique key

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, hierarchical-data, ssas

I'm currently building our Data Warehouse, primarily using Ralph Kimball's methods and guidance.

We are using the Microsoft stack for this (so SSIS, SSAS).

I am a bit stuck deciding how to handle BOMS (Bill of Materials) which is effectively an unbalanced hierarchy.

The BOM handles assemblies which are a collection of parts. Each part can have it's own child parts and each part can also appear more than once in different assemblies.

I'm trying to use a DimBOM table as follows...

[image]

Now in SSAS I can join the table to itself (ChildItemNumber to ItemNumber) and create a dimension. The dimension will pick up the relationship and create a parent-child link.

The problem is, The ItemNumber in this case is not necessarily unique (because a child item can be a parent itself). If I try to process the dimension SSAS warns about a non unique attribute key.

Is there a way of handling this, short of reverting to an exploded hierarchy e.g.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bimonkey.com](http://www.bimonkey.com/uploads/sql/recursive7.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case fetching hierarchies from SAP tables, after much searching on Internet and work I found the solution. You can find it in my blog here: http://biwithjb.wordpress.com/

It looks a bit complicated due to the SAP data complexities, but in the overall is quite simple... just a couple of tricks here and there ;)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing two things here which are the parts and the assemblies.
one of the key notions in a Parent Child Dimension is that though a father may have many children and grandchildren, a child may only have **one** parent.
so, i think the parts may be a Parent Child Dimension dimension of their own like:

parent key, child key, business key, name, amount
null, 45, A5286, connection rod, 
45, 51, B1452, bolt, 2
45, 52, B5874, rod, 1
(if you need 2 bolts and 1 rod to build a connection rod)

and assemblies may be another Parent Child Dimension:
parent key, child key, business key, name, amount
655, 745, E2497, Motorbike, 2
745, 874, E7482, engine, 1
(if you need 1 engine to build a motorbike)

and they can connect pehaps in a sort of fact where:
child key part, child key assembly, amount
45, 874, 3
(if you need 3 engine rods in one engine)
always try to connect at the lowest relevant level.

in any case, look at adventure works parent child dimension (the enterprise soloution has a few of them) and also look at the relational table and data of them.

hope it helped you find an answer that's relevant for you,
ella